# How is the IFB device positioned in the packet flow of the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, tc, netfilter

I would like to know the **exact position** of the following device in the packet flow for ingress traffic shaping:

- **IFB:** Intermediate Functional Block

I would like to better understand how packets are flowing to this device and exactly when this happens to understand what methods for filtering / classification can be used of the following:

- `tc filter ... u32 ...`
- `iptables ... -j MARK --set-mark ...`
- `iptables ... -j CLASSIFY --set-class ...`

It seems hard to find documentation on this topic, any help where to find official documentation would be greatly appreciated as well.

**Documentation as far as I know:**

- `tc`: [tldp.org HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/), [lartc.org HOWTO](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html)
- `ifb`: [linuxfoundation.org](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/ifb), [tc-mirred manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-mirred.8.html), [wiki.gentoo.org](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping)
- `netfilter` packet flow: [kernel_flow](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow), [docum.org kptd](http://www.docum.org/docum.org/kptd/)
  [image: Netfilter packet flow]

From the known documentation I interpret the following:

**Basic traffic control**

```
figure 1
+-------+                 +------+
|ingress|   +---------+   |egress|
|qdisc  +--->netfilter+--->qdisc |
|eth0   |   +---------+   |eth0  |
+-------+                 +------+
```

**IFB?**

`tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0` will result in?

```
figure 2
+-------+   +-------+   +------+                 +------+
|ingress|   |ingress|   |egress|   +---------+   |egress|
|qdisc  +--->qdisc  +--->qdisc +--->netfilter+--->qdisc |
|eth0   |   |ifb0   |   |ifb0  |   +---------+   |eth0  |
+-------+   +-------+   +------+                 +------+
```

Comment: maybe related: http://www.docum.org/docum.org/kptd/

Comment: I moved the part asking about **IMQ** to a [separate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289666/60293)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I finally understood how redirecting `ingress` to **`IFB`** is working:

```
+-------+   +------+                 +------+
|ingress|   |egress|   +---------+   |egress|
|qdisc  +--->qdisc +--->netfilter+--->qdisc |
|eth1   |   |ifb1  |   +---------+   |eth1  |
+-------+   +------+                 +------+
```

My initial assumption in `figure 2`, that the `ifb` device is inserted between `ingress eth1` and `netfilter` and that packets first enter the `ingress ifb1` and then exit through `egress ifb1` **was wrong**.

In fact redirecting traffic from an **interface's `ingress` or `egress`** to the **ifb's `egress`** is done directly by redirecting ("stealing") the packet and directly placing it in the `egress` of the ifb device.

Mirroring/redirecting traffic to the **ifb's `ingress`** is currently not supported as also stated in the documentation, at least on my version:

```
root@deb8:~# tc -V
tc utility, iproute2-ss140804
root@deb8:~# dpkg -l | grep iproute
ii  iproute2                       3.16.0-2
root@deb8:~# uname -a
Linux deb8 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Documentation

I was able to get this information thanks to the following documentation:

- linux-ip.net [Intermediate Functional Block](http://linux-ip.net/gl/tc-filters/tc-filters-node3.html)
- dev.laptop.org [ifb-README](http://dev.laptop.org/~mstone/sources/expanded_srpms/iproute-2.6.20-2.fc7/iproute-2.6.20-070313/doc/actions/ifb-README)
- people.netfilter.org [Linux Traffic Control Classifier-Action Subsystem Architecture Paper](http://people.netfilter.org/pablo/netdev0.1/papers/Linux-Traffic-Control-Classifier-Action-Subsystem-Architecture.pdf)

### Debugging

And some debugging using **`iptables -j LOG`** and **`tc filter action simple`**, which I used to print out messages to `syslog` when an `icmp` packet is flowing through the netdevs.

**The result is as follows:**

```
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341087] simple: tc[eth1]ingress_1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341114] simple: tc[ifb1]egress_1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341229] ipt[PREROUTING]raw IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341238] ipt[PREROUTING]mangle IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341242] ipt[PREROUTING]nat IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341249] ipt[INPUT]mangle IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341252] ipt[INPUT]filter IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341255] ipt[INPUT]nat IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:ee:8f:15:08:00:27:89:16:5b:08:00 SRC=10.1.1.3 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53979 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341267] ipt[OUTPUT]raw IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=10.1.1.2 DST=10.1.1.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37735 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341270] ipt[OUTPUT]mangle IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=10.1.1.2 DST=10.1.1.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37735 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341272] ipt[OUTPUT]filter IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=10.1.1.2 DST=10.1.1.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37735 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341274] ipt[POSTROUTING]mangle IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=10.1.1.2 DST=10.1.1.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37735 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=1382 SEQ=1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341278] simple: tc[eth1]egress_1
Jun 14 13:02:12 deb8 kernel: [ 4273.341280] simple: tc[ifb0]egress_1
```

**The debugging was done using the following settings:**

```
iptables -F -t filter
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -F -t raw
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]raw '
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]mangle '
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]nat '
iptables -A INPUT -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]mangle '
iptables -A INPUT -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]filter '
iptables -A INPUT -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]nat '
iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[FORWARD]mangle '
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[FORWARD]filter '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t raw -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]raw '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]mangle '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]nat '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]filter '
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[POSTROUTING]mangle '
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[POSTROUTING]nat '
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]raw '
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]mangle '
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[PREROUTING]nat '
iptables -A INPUT -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]mangle '
iptables -A INPUT -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]filter '
iptables -A INPUT -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[INPUT]nat '
iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[FORWARD]mangle '
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[FORWARD]filter '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t raw -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]raw '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]mangle '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]nat '
iptables -A OUTPUT -t filter -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[OUTPUT]filter '
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[POSTROUTING]mangle '
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'ipt[POSTROUTING]nat '

export TC="/sbin/tc"

$TC qdisc del dev eth1 root
$TC qdisc del dev eth1 ingress
ip link set dev ifb0 down
ip link set dev ifb1 down
$TC qdisc del dev ifb0 root
$TC qdisc del dev ifb1 root
rmmod ifb

modprobe ifb numifbs=2

$TC qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: htb default 2
$TC class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 2Mbit
$TC class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10Mbit
$TC filter add dev ifb0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff flowid 1:1 \
  action simple "tc[ifb0]egress"
$TC qdisc add dev ifb0 ingress
$TC filter add dev ifb0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff \
  action simple "tc[ifb0]ingress"

$TC qdisc add dev ifb1 root handle 1: htb default 2
$TC class add dev ifb1 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 2Mbit
$TC class add dev ifb1 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10Mbit
$TC filter add dev ifb1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff flowid 1:1 \
  action simple "tc[ifb1]egress"
$TC qdisc add dev ifb1 ingress
$TC filter add dev ifb1 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff \
  action simple "tc[ifb1]ingress"

ip link set dev ifb0 up
ip link set dev ifb1 up

$TC qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 2
$TC class add dev eth1 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 2Mbit
$TC class add dev eth1 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10Mbit
$TC filter add dev eth1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff flowid 1:1 \
  action simple "tc[eth1]egress" pipe \
  action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
$TC qdisc add dev eth1 ingress
$TC filter add dev eth1 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 \
  match ip protocol 1 0xff \
  action simple "tc[eth1]ingress" pipe \
  action mirred egress redirect dev ifb1
```