# How is the IMQ device positioned in the packet flow of the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, tc, netfilter

I would like to know the **exact position** of the following device in the packet flow for ingress traffic shaping:

- **IFB:** Intermediate Functional Block

I would like to better understand how packets are flowing to this device and exactly when this happens to understand what methods for filtering / classification can be used of the following:

- `tc filter ... u32 ...`
- `iptables ... -j MARK --set-mark ...`
- `iptables ... -j CLASSIFY --set-class ...`

It seems hard to find documentation on this topic, any help where to find official documentation would be greatly appreciated as well.

**Documentation as far as I know:**

- `tc`: [tldp.org HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/), [lartc.org HOWTO](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html)
- `imq`: [IMQ - FAQ](https://github.com/imq/linuximq/wiki/FAQ), [lartc.org](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.imq.html)
- `netfilter` packet flow: [kernel_flow](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow), [docum.org kptd](http://www.docum.org/docum.org/kptd/)
  [image: Netfilter packet flow]

From the known documentation I interpret the following:

**Basic traffic control**

```
figure 1
+-------+                 +------+
|ingress|   +---------+   |egress|
|qdisc  +--->netfilter+--->qdisc |
|eth0   |   +---------+   |eth0  |
+-------+                 +------+
```

**IMQ?**

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j IMQ --todev 0` will result in?

```
figure 2
+----------+   +-------+   +------+   +----------+
|PREROUTING|   |ingress|   |egress|   |PREROUTING|
|mangle    +--->qdisc  +--->qdisc +--->nat       |
|          |   |imq0   |   |imq0  |   |          |
+----------+   +-------+   +------+   +----------+
```

and `iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j IMQ --todev 1` will result in?

```
figure 3
+-----------+   +-------+   +------+   +------+
|POSTROUTING|   |ingress|   |egress|   |egress|
|nat        +--->qdisc  +--->qdisc +--->qdisc |
|           |   |imq1   |   |imq1  |   |eth0  |
+-----------+   +-------+   +------+   +------+
```

Comment: I separated this question which is only related to **IMQ** from the [original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288959/60293) which was asking about IFB and IMQ and is now only about IFB.  Thanks also to [@frostschutz](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) providing the link to docum.org